# Kali 2.0 Reaver 1.5.2 EAPOL request times out error (code: 0x02)

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, timeout

Hi and thanks very much in advance for any help. I am new to Kali and `reaver` and am encountering an issue with `EAPOL` requests getting stuck.

To explain the whole situation, `reaver` itself won't associate with the AP without either `airodump-ng`, `areplay-ng` or wash running in another terminal, but associates once one of them is running and when using the `-A` switch.

Commands and output below, obfuscated for obvious reasons. I have run a `tcpdump` as well and can see responses from the AP but `reaver` doesn't appear to collect them.

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng check kill
Killing these processes:
PID Name
776 wpa_supplicant

root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan0
No interfering processes found
PHY     Interface   Driver      Chipset
phy0    wlan0       iwlwifi     Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
        (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]wlan0mon)
        (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlan0)

root@kali:~#airodump-ng wlan0mon<br>

BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -48       48       21    0   1  54e  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -57       20        0    0   6  54e. WPA2 CCMP   MGT  xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -58       19        0    0   6  54e. WPA2 CCMP   PSK  xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -59       24        0    0   6  54e. OPN              xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -79       29        1    0   5  54e  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -83       17        0    0  11  54e  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -83       13        0    0  11  54e  WPA2 CCMP   MGT  xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  -83       19        0    0  11  54e  OPN              xxx
```

`Reaver` is then run in a separate terminal, otherwise it just hangs waiting to associate

```
root@kali:~# reaver -i wlan0mon -b xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -A -S -N -a -vv -K 1

Reaver v1.5.2 WiFi Protected Setup Attack Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>
mod by t6_x <t6_x@hotmail.com> & DataHead & Soxrok2212

[+] Waiting for beacon from xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
[+] Switching wlan0mon to channel 1 
[+] Associated with xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (ESSID: xxxxx) 
[+] Starting Cracking Session. Pin count: 0, Max pin attempts: 11000 
[+] Trying pin 12345670.
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[!] WARNING: 25 successive start failures
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!]  WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670.
```

It will then just loop continuously.

Comment: Welcome!  Thank you for giving such great information.  Do you know if there might also be some useful information in the system log files?

Comment: DreadMonkey: It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/140843/dreadmonkey and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/140894/dreadmonkey.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on and accept answers to this question.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses and help in merging these accounts. RobertL -  I did try and find some log files but couldn't locate anything of use, possibly down to not looking in the right place. Could you possible point me in the direction of the logs you're thinking of?